# Debugging web page in Android app using weinre - cannot find debug target

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, remote-debugging, weinre

I am trying to debug a web page inside my Android app's WebView.

I've setup and started weinre following [these](http://dustint.com/post/482/getting-started-with-weinre-mobile-debugging-on-windows) and [these](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Running.html) instructions, modified my web page adding

```
<script src="http://my-local-ip:8080/target/target-script-min.js"></script>
```

Now, as I understand, I should open `http://localhost:8080/client/#anonymous` in Chrome and find my debug target there. However the targets list is empty.

What have I missed or done wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weinre not working, trying to debug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444851/weinre-not-working-trying-to-debug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to use IP address both in Debug Target and Debug Client, i.e.

```
http://my-local-ip:8080/client/#anonymous
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue is gone after changed "127.0.0.1" to real ip like "192.168.0.42".