# Weinre not working, trying to debug?

Tags: android, cordova

I think I may be missing something, but I have installed the .apk on my android tablet with the script

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

in the header.

I decided to try running it locally following http://forums.adobe.com/docs/DOC-2623. I went to "localhost:8080" and weinre is installed, but I still get the same thing "target not found".

I think I am missing a step, or I am not completely understanding how it connects to my app?

I have also tried building it via build.phonegap.com enabling debug mode, then installing the apk then clicking debug, gosh the steps are nice and easy but I can't get it to work.

I have to be missing something, so I hope someone can help me understand what I am missing.

**Solved:** Thanks to *@Christian Kuetbach* following his answer helped, let me add a few things just in case someone else has this issue.

1. I made sure the script weinre gives you to add is loaded last, I put it at the very bottom, because I figured it should load after everything. Just did this to make sure.
2. Make sure to connect to weinre properly, @Christian Kuetbach says it `--boundHost -all-` but I had to enter it like this `weinre --boundHost -all-` maybe adding the weinre is an obvious thing, but it could cause confusion, so make sure to do that I am running on win8 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you start the weinre server part at the android device?

I think you'll nee to use the IP of you server (You Dev-Computer) in the HTML.

In case of Windows 8: https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=27309

In that example above the IP is `144.92.124.118`

```
<script src="http://144.92.124.118:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

**update**
This will only work, if the device is online and in the same network as your PC and the firewall is configured to allow connections and weinre server is started with the parameter  -`-boundHost -all-`

Comment: Yeah I used localhost:8080 that didnt seem right to me, but I am no expert in making remote connections or anything of that matter. How do I get the ip of the development pc running on local host. I mean I tried the hosted version of weinre to no success as well.

Comment: Might need to add edge inspect chrome addon? I am trying it now well see, fingers crossed.

Comment: How did you develop your cordova application? Do you use a Wondows PC,Linux or Mac OSX? In case of windows 'ipconfig /all' else 'sudo ifconfig'. There you will see you IP-address. For example '192.168.0.2'

Comment: Ah ok let me see, I developed on win 8.

Comment: Okay got it, so I should use that in place of localhost? Okay thanks for the help this was very clear, let me try it.

Comment: Gotta recompile and stuff, so ill be right back.. I hope it works smooth :)

Comment: SAHWEET!! It worked, I am going to add a few notes on some things I did that may have also helped, not sure, but what I do know is adding the ip address did help! You're the man...